# segmentation fault

Tags: linux, c, qt

Программа в qtcreator на линуксе падает с ошибкой "segmentation fault".

```
 int segment_id;
    int shmid;
    char* shared_memory;
    struct shmid_ds shmbuffer;
    const int shared_segment_size = 0x500000;


    segment_id=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,shared_segment_size,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    shared_memory = (char*)shmat(segment_id,0,0);
    sprintf(shared_memory, "dfdsf");
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_STAT, &shmbuffer);
    printf("\n Размер выделенного блока:%d", shmbuffer.shm_segsz);
    shmdt(shared_memory);
    shared_memory = (char*) shmat(segment_id, (void*)0x6400,0);
    printf("\n Сегмент переподключения адреса %p", shared_memory);
    printf("%s",shared_memory);


    shmdt(shared_memory);
    shmctl(segment_id,IPC_RMID,0);
```

Подскажите что не так, в си не особо разбираюсь.

Comment: Вы когда нибудь слышали о "минимальном примере, который воспроизводить проблему"? Попробуйте его сделать.

Comment: Чему равны указатели `segment_id` и `shared_memory`, случайно не `NULL`?

Comment: Не знаю. Вроде же segment_id должен присвоиться идентификатор.

Comment: Убрав строку printf("%s",shared_memory); всё заработало. Не совсем понимаю почему.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в повторном подключении памяти `shared_memory = (char*) shmat(segment_id, (void*)0x6400,0);`

У Вас нет проверки возпращаемых кодов, поэтому программа продолжает выполняться даже после ошибки в `shmat`. В случает ошибки `shmat()` возвращает `-1`, и при попытке распечатать строку по этому адресу происходит segmentation fault.

Увы не могу назвать причину ошибки `shmat`, так как не знаю физики использования параметров `shmaddr` и `shmflg`, но у меня система сообщает о "неправильных аргументах":

```
 shared_memory = (char*) shmat(segment_id, (void*)0x6400,0);
 if ((void *) -1 == shared_memory)
 {
    printf ("error shmat, errno=%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
 }
```

значение `erno` выводит как `Invalid argument`, а в `shared_memory` остаётся `-1`.